# Pageview.Builder inside Futurebuilder is throwing errors

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, widget

I'm relatively new to Flutter So I have the following code, I've been reading futurebuilder and it seems to be the most appropriate builder for my situation.

```
class CardCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardCarousel({super.key});

  @override
  State<CardCarousel> createState() => _CardCarouselState();
}

class _CardCarouselState extends State<CardCarousel> {
  List<String> imagePaths = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initImages();
  }

  Future<List<String>> _initImages() async {
    final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
    List<String> imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
        .where((String key) => key.contains('assets/images/png/'))
        .where((String key) => key.contains('.png'))
        .toList();

    return imagePaths;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _initImages(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Text('NO IMAGES');
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  imagePaths = snapshot.data!;
                });
              }
              break;
            case ConnectionState.none:
              print('NONE');
              break;
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              print('WAITING');
              break;
            case ConnectionState.active:
              print('active');
              break;
          }

          return PageView.builder(
              controller: controller,
              itemCount: imagePaths.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                return CustomCard(imageURL: imagePaths[index]);
              });
        });
  }
}
```

it throws the following error:

```
This CardCarousel widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
```

Is this an instance where a particular entry is null? or should I add more conditional renders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `setState` there, so replace

```
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Text('NO IMAGES');
          } else {
            setState(() {
              imagePaths = snapshot.data!;
            });
          }
```

with

```
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Text('NO IMAGES');
          } else {
            imagePaths = snapshot.data!;
          }
```

Comment: Please do explain. I know setState triggers a re-render but I've learned from online courses that whenever you want to update your UI and change the value of the dependent state you should setState, I didn't know you can normally assign to a variable like this.

Comment: @Jam the FutureBuilder itself rebuilds already with each change of the connection state of the future, so no need to trigger any extra rebuilds.